Why a web service request is working from browser but from jQuery?
I've never faced this situation before. A call to
https://example.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&moodlewsrestformat=json&wsfunction=core_user_get_users_by_field&field=username&values[0]=99999999

is working when I connect to it from the browser's URL bar. However, when I set a breakpoint in the firefox debugger to watch the response in JQuery, I get an Invalid parameter exception.
Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thank you all.

check your network tab, most probably the resulting query is not the same ...

ok, sorry, error was on some parameter having a wrong quoting.

i´m glad it helped ;) i was just guessing based on "invalid parameter"
